# create progress bar when login button is clicked and when verification gets over from webserver

Tags: android, web-services, progress-bar

how to do when i click on login button progress bar should display and when backend process gets over progress bar gets dismiss and moved to other activity 
??? hw to do this ??

pleae provide piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with AsyncTask and ProgressDialog

`private ProgressDialog progress`;

```
    progress= new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setMessage("I am thinking");

private class MyAsynch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...strings) { // <== DO NOT TOUCH THE UI VIEW HERE
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String key= strings[0];
        String inString= strings[1];
        return encrypt(key, inString); // <== return value String result is sent to onPostExecute
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        progress.dismiss();
        editTextConfusedText.setText(result); // you could launch results dialog here
    }
};

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (asynch != null) {asynch.cancel(true);}
    if (progress != null){progress.cancel();}
}
```

Comment: On onPause was not available in the SDK I used. onCancelled was. Buildtools : 21.1.2 and compileSdkVersion : 21

Answer (score 0):

**Combine these 2 tutorials** ( Eclipse source code on the bottom of the posts )

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-series-from-sql-php-to-xml-json-to-android-listview/

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-progress-dialog/